# view-less fields in rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I use scaffold to create a model, how to have some fields not to appear in views? I am talking about fields such as user_id, is there something else that I need to do to secure this field?

Answer (score 0):

Andy, your question is ambiguous, First you indicate that you don't want the field to appear in your views and then you mention "secure" which is usually associated to attr_accessible()

To have the field "not show up in your views" don't write them in there in the first place!  :)  Seriously,  I assume from your question, that you are using scaffolding.  If so, then just remove the field from the views after the scaffolding has generated them